# How to fix trainer package not found in AI Platform GPU-distributed training job

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm attempting to train a Tensorflow Estimator on AI Platform. The model trains on local perfectly fine, albeit extremely slowly, but right when I try to run distributed-GPU training on AI Platform I run into this error:

```
CommandException: No URLs matched: gs://path/.../trainer-0.1.tar.gz
```

I have my code packaged with the `trainer` module as recommended by Google Cloud AI Platform. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you send an email with job id to cloudml-feedback@google.com please? It's hard to judge only based on an error msg. Thanks!

Comment: I was actually able to fix my issue: it appears that if I don't set up a staging bucket then the model dir where checkpoints are stored will overwrite the trainer package before the worker replicas are able to download the trainer! Adding the staging bucket fixed this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to fix my issue: it appears that if I don't set up a staging bucket then the model dir where checkpoints are stored will overwrite the trainer package before the worker replicas are able to download the trainer! I'm unsure how the checkpoints were even able to begin being stored when the worker replicas hadn't all downloaded the trainer yet, but adding the staging bucket that was different from my model dir fixed this.